# how to delete a row?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a table with edit, create and delete options of record. But I have a issue in deleting operation. When am trying to delete the last row of table, all the rows are deleted except the first row. Please provide the solution ?? how can I delete the particular selected record ??

> **Apex class**

```
public class addRowRemoveRow{

    public List<Account> allAccs {get; set;}
    public string SelectedAccountId {get; set;}
    public static Integer toDelIdent {get; set;}


    public addRowRemoveRow(){
        allAccs = new List<Account>();
        Account acc1 = new Account();
        allAccs.add(acc1);
    }

    public void addRowMethod(){
        Account acc1 = new Account();
        allAccs.add(acc1);
    }

    public void removeRowMethod(){
        integer count = allAccs.size();
        system.debug('size----->'+count);
        allAccs.remove(count--);
    }

    public void saveMethod(){
        insert allAccs;
        clearMethod();
    }



    public void clearMethod(){
        integer finalCount = allAccs.size();
        allAccs.clear();
        for(integer i=0;i<finalCount;i++){
            Account acc1 = new Account();
            allAccs.add(acc1);

        }

    }


}
```

> **VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="addRowRemoveRow">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock id="anyName">
          <apex:dataTable value="{!allAccs}" var="Accvariable" cellpadding="4" border="1">
          <apex:column headerValue="Action">
              <apex:outputLink >Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
             <apex:outputLink >Del</apex:outputLink>

              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Model">
                  <apex:inputtext value="{!Accvariable.Name}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Version">
                  <apex:inputtext value="{!Accvariable.Phone}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Discount">
                  <apex:inputtext value="{!Accvariable.website}"/>
              </apex:column>
         </apex:dataTable>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="TOP">
          <apex:commandButton value="addRow" action="{!addRowMethod}" rerender="anyName" />
         <!-- <apex:commandButton value="removeRow" action="{!removeRowMethod}"/>-->

              <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveMethod}"/>
<!--          <apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clearMethod}" reRender="anyName" />-->
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't see it currently in your visualforce page, but is it safe to assume that you are encountering this problem when using the addRowRemoveRow() method?

Comment: Agree with Martin. This could also be a rerender issue. Could you please update the code snippet at the time you had the issue?

Comment: In removeRowMethod() am encountering a problem. how can I change that method to delete a particular row which am trying to delete ?

Comment: <apex:pageBlock id="anyName"><apex:dataTable value="{!allAccs}" var="Accvariable" cellpadding="4" border="1">
<apex:column headerValue="Action">
  <apex:outputLink >Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
 <apex:outputLink >Del</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column><apex:column headerValue="Model">
 <apex:inputtext value="{!Accvariable.Name}"/></apex:column>
 .. .</apex:dataTable><apex:pageBlockButtons location="TOP">
  <apex:commandButton value="addRow" action="{!addRowMethod}"rerender="anyName" /><apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveMethod}"/></apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>

Comment: code is too long..i shorted it

Answer (score 1):

For delete the selected row you can use [wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). It is more better approach. There is a sample given in this link you can check here.

if you want to delete permanently on edit click then you can use map in controller, pass `record id` using param in the controller and then delete the record using DML. You can take help from [here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html)

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: without selecting the checkbox by clicking the "edit" output link  of the row I want to delete the record.

Comment: @prabu permanent delete the record or just want to remove from the list.

Comment: In both case you can use map, pass selected record id using param in controller and then remove the row  from map or delete the record using id.

Comment: want to delete the record permanently..!!

Comment: then you can use map , pass record id using param and then delete the record using DML. You can take help from [here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html)